# Xamarin ListView System.MissingMethodException: Method 'TextView.SetTextAppearance' not found

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to display list of strings in ListView.
In my xaml i have:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListCollections" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

In code I have:

```
ListCollections.ItemsSource = new string[]{"one", "two"};
```

When i run app i got:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'TextView.SetTextAppearance' not found.
```

I am using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.49 and Visual studio 2015. Emulator is Android 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug already reported in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41276).

Has i said there:

> I only was able to run this when setting the target API to 23.

Please try to set your Android target to 23.

Comment: But now I cannot deploy for my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0 :/ And my target device is Lenovo TAB2 A10-70L with android 5.0. What can I do?

Comment: Whats your min API?

Comment: Compile using: 6, Minimum 4.4 ( tried 4.0 too) and target 6.0

Comment: When deploying to Samsung:1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE], when running od emulator with 5.0 it is running OK

Comment: You need to remove the the app manually from your Samsung. Remove mono runtime too (Go to applications and remove  them). And then install the app again.

Comment: Yeap it is working. Application was not installed (has 0 bytes) but was on the list.